# How to find matrixs between two inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $\left< \cdot,\cdot \right>_1, \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_2$, inner product on $V$. Show that there are unique matrices $A$ and $B$, such that
$$
\left< x,y \right>_2=\left<Ax,y\right>_1 \textrm{ and } \left<x,y\right>_1=\left<Bx,y\right>_2.
$$

I don't know how to find relations between two inner product.

Comment: A = B, o$r AXA^{-1} = y $ and $ BXB^{-1} = y$

Comment: How to prove your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since $V$ is an abstract vector space, $A,B$ should be linear transformations and not matrices. How to find $A$? Assume first that $A$ exists and choose an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ for $(V,\left<\cdot, \cdot\right>_1)$. Plugging it into the equality $\left< x, y \right>_2 = \left< Ax, y \right>_1$, we get

$$ \left<e_i, e_j \right>_2 = \left<Ae_i, e_j \right>_1. $$

Since $(e_i)$ is an orthonormal basis for $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_1$, we have

$$ Ae_i = \sum_j \left<Ae_i, e_j \right>_1 e_j = \sum_{j} \left<e_i, e_j \right>_2 e_j. $$

This proves uniqueness. Now define $A \colon V \rightarrow V$ by the formula above and show that $A$ indeed satisfies $\left<x, y \right>_2 = \left<Ax, y \right>_1$ for all $x,y \in V$.

The matrix $B$ is obtained by the same argument with $\left<\cdot, \cdot \right>_1$ replaced by $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>_2$.